# Is there direct evidence of flowing glaciers on Mars?

Tags: mars, mars-orbiters

I know that analysis of Mars photographs has revealed what appear to be the kinds of surface ripples that occur due to glacial flow.  For example, this photo, taken from [here](https://twitter.com/peter_grindrod/status/955476910573785088):
[image: mars glacier]
The glaciers appear to be covered by meters-thick layers of dust, protecting them from sublimation.

If the glaciers are flowing, then it seems they should be "calving": chunks should be falling off of their leading edges. Or, since the glaciers would be flowing onto land instead of into liquid water, the leading edges might be "plowing" the regolith. Has photographic evidence been found, showing *changes* at the leading edges, to indicate that this is happening?

Comment: I don't believe it is a covered glacier, it may be the remains of a glacier vanished a long time ago.

Comment: My source was https://earthsky.org/space/mars-has-belts-of-glaciers.  Not an original source, but the original can be tracked down from there.

Comment: If there was a glacial flow and there is still a covered glacier, why the ice does not flow anymore? If the ice still does flow, why it did not disapear? Is there a source of fresh ice at the top of the glacier from fallen snow?

Comment: All good questions.  Maybe there are covered glaciers, but maybe Mars is cold enough that the ice is a lot stiffer than ice in terrestrial glaciers and therefore doesn't flow.  Or, maybe the ice does flow but the photographic evidence is lacking.  Or, maybe there is evidence.  That's what I'm asking about.